# Ogone/Ingenico - An error has occurred; please try again later

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment

I am working with Ogone for making online payments in my PHP application but I face very strange behaviour. This is my form:

```
 $sha = "ACCEPTURL=" . $accepturl . "&id=" . $orderid . $options["ogone_SHA"] . 
     "AMOUNT=" . $total . $options["ogone_SHA"] .
     "CANCELURL=" . $declineurl . "&id=" . $orderid . $options["ogone_SHA"] .
     "CURRENCY=EUR" . $options["ogone_SHA"] .
     "DECLINEURL=" . $declineurl . "&id=" . $orderid . $options["ogone_SHA"] .
     "LANGUAGE=" . $lang . $options["ogone_SHA"] .
     "ORDERID=" . $orderid . $options["ogone_SHA"] .
     "PSPID=". $options["ogone_pspid"] . $options["ogone_SHA"];

  $sha1 = sha1($sha);


<form id="ogone" action="<?=$options["ogone_url"]?>" method="post"  target="_blank">
   <input type="hidden" name="orderID" value="<?=$orderid?>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="pspid" value="<?=$options["ogone_pspid"]?>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="EUR" />
   <input type="hidden" name="language" value="<?=$lang?>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?=$total?>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="accepturl" value="<?=$accepturl?>&id=<?=$orderid?>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="declineurl" value="<?=$declineurl?>&id=<?=$orderid?>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="cancelurl" value="<?=$declineurl?>&id=<?=$orderid?>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="SHASign" value="<?=$sha1?>" />

<noscript>
  <input type="submit" value="<?=CONFIRM?>" />
</noscript>
  </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var options = {
        target:        '_blank'
    };
   $('#ogone').ajaxForm(options);

  document.getElementById('ogone').submit();
  setTimeout("document.location = 'index.php?reload=nocache'", 3000);
 });

</script>
```

When submitting it for the first time in certain browser, I got an error when redirected to Ogone:

> An error has occurred; please try again later. If you are the owner or the integrator of this website, please log into the Ogone back office to see the details of the error.

No details for the error in the error log in my ogone account.

Submitting it again - everything is ok. Reproduced on every browser I tried - the very first submitting is unsuccessfull, after that everything is ok. I have tried to clear the browser history and cookies to see if this is related to the problem - no success.

Any clue on what might be happening here will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that browsers are blocking my app to POST data to the payment provider for the first time. I needed to allow sending data to this website.

Comment: How did you do that? can you pls tell. I am also facing this issue

Comment: Browser is showing dialog which asks if you allow submitting data to this website. Click "allow" and try again.